# Minimizing sum of squared distances from point to spheres

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given some spheres with known radius and known origin in three dimensional space, I want to find the point P that lies "closest" to all these spheres. The meassure of closeness, I guess, will be the sum of the squared distances from the point P to each of the spheres.

Is there any good solution to this problem? Any numerical solution that will converge to give the correct answer, or any fixed solution? As far as I know this problem is neither convex nor linear, so I am fearing the worst.

(With close to sphere, I mean close to the boundary of the sphere. If it lies outside or inside does not matter.)

Comment: It may help to think of the distance to the sphere as the distance to the center minus the radius of the sphere. (This produces a negative result for points inside a sphere, but the square is the same.)

Comment: I tried to explain it, but it was maybe not very clear: The point can be inside one of the spheres, that is no problem. Then the distance will simply be the distance to the boundary of the sphere. If for instance the points lies in the origin of a sphere with radius 1, the distance to the sphere will be 1. So if we as an example have three spheres where two of them are going through the origin (center) of the third one, the solution will (if I'm correct) be inside the third sphere.

Comment: For any one sphere's contribution to the objective function, this is naturally radially symmetric.  If you think about the 1D version of this (variable being radius), the distance to the sphere is continuous but not differentiable at the boundary and at the center of the sphere.  Squaring the distance smooths out the function as you pass through the sphere, but it leaves that point at the center of non-differentiability.  That would motivate me to evaluate the objective function at the sphere's centers, and thereafter use some pruning or barrier methods to search away from the centers.

Answer (score 1):

If the centers are given by the points $y_i$ and the radii are $r_i$, the function to minimize is:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N (\|x-y_i\| - r_i)^2
$$

The function is not differentiable at the centers $y_i$, but everywhere else the gradient is given by the formula:

$$
\nabla f(x) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^N x-y_i - r_i\frac{x-y_i}{\|x-y_i\|}
$$

So minimizers of $f$ are either one of the centers, or else satisfy $\nabla f(x)=0$, equivalently:
$$
x = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i + r_i\frac{x-y_i}{\|x-y_i\|}
$$

This suggests using the fixed-point iteration:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_0 &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i \\
x_{t+1} &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i + r_i\frac{x_{t}-y_i}{\|x_t-y_i\|}
\end{aligned}
$$
No guarantees this will work, but testing it out on a few problems with 1000 points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and it seemed to converge linearly.

Comment: This also has a nice interpretation as follows: The problem is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_i\|x-p_i\|^2$ such that the points $p_i$ lie on the given spheres. Your algorithm is equivalent to minimizing $x$ and $p_i$ alternately.

Answer (score 0):

The distance from $P$ to a sphere $S_i$ can be expressed as

$d_i = \max \{ ||P-C_i||_2 - R_i, R_i - ||P-C_i||_2\},$

so that your problem is

$\min \sum d^2_i $

$ d_i \geq  ||P-C_i||_2 - R_i \quad i=1,...$

$ d_i \geq   R_i - ||P-C_i||_2\quad i=1,...$

This is a nonconvex smooth nonlinear optimization problem, due to the second set of constraints. In general I guess some randomized algorithm coupled with smooth local searches would do. But of course depends on how many spheres.

Comment: This formulation doesn't match the problem posed in the Question, esp. given the clarification by the Comment that distances are to the surfaces of spheres from $P \in X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You are right, I guess I was writing while the description was changing. I fix it.

Comment: The OP asks about minimizing a sum of squares of distances, not the sum of distances.  Also the distance from $P$ to the center of a sphere is not at issue, but rather distance to the nearest point on the sphere.  See my Comment on the other Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to formulate this as a Lagrange multiplier problem. As said, the squared distance from (x, y, z) to a sphere with radius $r_1$ and centre $(a_1, b_1, c_1)$ is $d_1^2 = (x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2+(z-c_1)^2 - r_1^2$ and minus this if the point is inside the sphere. Let's look for a solution outside the 3 spheres (well separated spheres?). Then we have the Lagrange function

$L = d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2 - \alpha C_1-\beta C_2-\gamma C_3$

where $C_1$ is the constraint $(x_1-a_1)^2+(y_1-b_1)^2+(z_1-c_1)^2 - r_1^2 = 0$ and $C_1$ and $C_2$ are similarly defined in terms of variables $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ and $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$.
The Lagrange equations to solve will then be in terms of 15 variables $(x, y, z)$, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ and $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$. Mathematica or some such might be able to solve these equations.

Comment: For a point $(x,y,z)$ outside the sphere of radius $r$ centered at $(a,b,c)$ the contribution to the objective function is $(\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2} - r)^2$, and the same formula applies if a point is inside the sphere, the negative difference with $r$ being squared and making a positive contribution to the objective.